# C++11 Optional Template Type Parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

If I want to write a class that has an optional type parameter I can do the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
        T t;
};

template<>
struct X<void>
{

};

int main()
{
        X<int> a;
        X<void> b;
};
```

Is there a way to write it so that the void is unnecessary?  ie:

```
int main()
{
        X<int> a;
        X b;
};
```

I tried this:

```
template<typename T = void>
struct X
{
    T t;
};

template<>
struct X<void>
{

};

int main()
{
    X<int> a;
    X b;
};
```

but I get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:16:4: error: missing template arguments before ‘b’
test.cpp:16:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b’
```

Comment: The best you can do is `X<> b`.

Comment: The only solution I know to not using templates is to make a non-templated sub-class.

Comment: You did everything correctly in your second attempt, except that you are still required to specify empty `<>` when instantiating your template with default argument, i.e. it has to be `X<> b;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You technically need to write:

```
X<> b;
```

But you can simply fix that ugliness with a typedef:

```
typedef X<> Y;
```

And then you can do:

```
Y b;
```

Comment: In which case you can just as well do `typedef X<void> Y;` and avoid the default value.

Answer (score 1):

If only this was possible:

```
template <typename T>
using X = std::is_void<T>::value ? _X<> : _X<T>
```

But this doesn't compile so unfortunately you are stuck with a `typedef` like the other answer.

Comment: There is `typename std::conditional<std::is_void<T>::value, _X<> : _X<T>>::type`. I know this is old, but it's worth sharing.